# Facing issue running Pig in local mode, failing in java udf

Tags: java, apache-pig

I have a Pig UDF (written in Java) which reads data from a JSON file present in HDFS and does further calculation.

Below is the line of code (last line in the snippet) which is giving error. Because it is unable to connect to HDFS to find the file.

```
Path path = new Path(filename);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(path)));
```

But my pig unit is passing, no issue with that.

I want to write a generic code which runs in both modes of execution local and mapreduce.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to call something like this

```
FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(UDFContext.getUDFContext().getJobConf());
```

But if your hdfs has any kind of security, I expect this to also fail.  Pig local mode is purely for local and skips loading any configuration because of that.
https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/a6c1a59eb42b600229bbe7f92b74363b515c1dfc/src/org/apache/pig/Main.java#L356-L358

Comment: No, this did not work Koji. Still the UDF is trying to refer to HDFS even when running in local.

Comment: Do you have hdfs:// in your filename?  In local mode, default file system is local and not hdfs.

Comment: I misunderstood that you WANTED the udf to access hdfs file during local mode.  But instead, are you asking somehow your UDF is trying to access hdfs even in local mode?

Comment: No Koji, my udf is trying to access HDFS. But I want my udf to access local file system.

Comment: I see.  In that case, question would be how you're running in "local mode".  Somehow, you're Configuration is still pointing to "hdfs" as default filesystem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was working on other priorities. 
Yeah somehow the udf is accessing hdfs instead of local fs when running pig in local mode